# Icon JumpList Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This Link work

```
string notepadPath = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "notepad.exe");
                JumpListLink jlNotepad = new JumpListLink(notepadPath, "Notepad");
                jlNotepad.IconReference = new IconReference(notepadPath, 0);
```

but in this link the icon doesn't appear

```
string myapp = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "MyApp.exe");
            JumpListLink jlapp = new JumpListLink(myapp, "My App");
            jlapp.IconReference = new IconReference(myapp, 0);
```

why?

The icon work only file of Windows =(

Answer (score 2):

You should add an icon as embedded resource to your .NET windows forms application. Then it will work.

have a look at this article on Code Project: [Windows 7 / VS2010 demo app](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MefFX.aspx#pre)